# pandas: how to do multiple groupby-apply operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have more experience with R’s `data.table`, but am trying to learn `pandas`. In `data.table`, I can do something like this:

```
> head(dt_m)
   event_id           device_id longitude latitude               time_ category
1:  1004583 -100015673884079572        NA       NA 1970-01-01 06:34:52   1 free
2:  1004583 -100015673884079572        NA       NA 1970-01-01 06:34:52   1 free
3:  1004583 -100015673884079572        NA       NA 1970-01-01 06:34:52   1 free
4:  1004583 -100015673884079572        NA       NA 1970-01-01 06:34:52   1 free
5:  1004583 -100015673884079572        NA       NA 1970-01-01 06:34:52   1 free
6:  1004583 -100015673884079572        NA       NA 1970-01-01 06:34:52   1 free
                 app_id is_active
1: -5305696816021977482         0
2: -7164737313972860089         0
3: -8504475857937456387         0
4: -8807740666788515175         0
5:  5302560163370202064         0
6:  5521284031585796822         0


dt_m_summary <- dt_m[,
                     .(
                       mean_active = mean(is_active, na.rm = TRUE)
                       , median_lat = median(latitude, na.rm = TRUE)
                       , median_lon = median(longitude, na.rm = TRUE)
                       , mean_time = mean(time_)
                       , new_col = your_function(latitude, longitude, time_)
                     )
                     , by = list(device_id, category)
                     ]
```

The new columns (`mean_active` through `new_col`), as well as `device_id` and `category`, will appear in `dt_m_summary`. I could also do a similar `by` transformation in the original table if I want a new column that has the results of the groupby-apply:

`dt_m[, mean_active := mean(is_active, na.rm = TRUE), by = list(device_id, category)]`

(in case I wanted, e.g., to select rows where `mean_active` is greater than some threshold, or do something else).

I know there is `groupby` in `pandas`, but I haven’t found a way of doing the sort of easy transformations as above. The best I could think of was doing a series of groupby-apply’s and then merging the results into one `dataframe`, but that seems very clunky. Is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 6):

IIUC, use `groupby` and `agg`.  See [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) for more information.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2),
                  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('XY'), range(5)]),
                  list('AB'))

df
```

[image]

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(['sum', 'count', 'std'])
```

[image]

---

A more tailored example would be

```
# level=0 means group by the first level in the index
# if there is a specific column you want to group by
# use groupby('specific column name')
df.groupby(level=0).agg({'A': ['sum', 'std'],
                         'B': {'my_function': lambda x: x.sum() ** 2}})
```

[image]

***Note*** the `dict` passed to the `agg` method has keys `'A'` and `'B'`.  This means, run the functions `['sum', 'std']` for `'A'` and `lambda x: x.sum() ** 2` for `'B'` (and label it `'my_function'`)

***Note 2*** pertaining to your `new_column`.  `agg` requires that the passed functions reduce columns to scalars.  You're better off adding the new column ahead of the `groupby`/`agg`

Comment: Don't forget the lambda. `new_col = your_function(latitude, longitude, time_)`

Comment: So, how would call `my_function` taking multiple arguments would look like? Imagine it’s a long function with a bunch of lines.

Comment: The issue I am seeing is that in my work, it’s rarely the case there is only one variable being transformed by some function. I don’t usually need to find a sum of A only. I have a function that maybe takes several columns of the data. Then I need to have the results of that function applied to the aggregated rows (similar to X and Y) and have a choice what to call the columns. Are you saying that I have to pre-generate the columns in a new dataframe and then… what?

Comment: @Anarcho-Chossid We often ask people to present their questions in adherence to the MCVE principles  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  In your case, I took a guess at what you needed because I didn't quite understand what you wanted to do with `your_function`.  I'd ask you to rethink your question and be explicit in what you are asking.  Show explicitly what you expect your output to look like.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was obvious that I want to do some sort of unique transformation with `new_col = your_function(latitude, longitude, time_)`. E.g., I want to take cos(lat) + sin(lon) - tan(_time) and assign the result to some new variable (I just made it up, but I hope it illustrates the point).

Comment: @Anarcho-Chossid The confusion is in that you stated you want to summarize the data (reduce dimensionality) as well as transform.  I wasn't sure if you wanted to sumarize the transformation or somehow have a result with a dimension 1 transformation along side other dimension 0 summary stats (which wouldn't work, really).  You didn't make that clear.  You could make it clear with a cobbled together table of what you think it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

@piRSquared has a great answer but in your particular case I think you might be interested in using pandas very flexible [apply function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).  Because it can be applied to each group one at a time you can operate on multiple columns within the grouped DataFrame simultaneously.

```
def your_function(sub_df):
    return np.mean(np.cos(sub_df['latitude']) + np.sin(sub_df['longitude']) - np.tan(sub_df['time_']))

def group_function(g):
    return pd.Series([g['is_active'].mean(), g['latitude'].median(), g['longitude'].median(), g['time_'].mean(), your_function(g)], 
                     index=['mean_active', 'median_lat', 'median_lon', 'mean_time', 'new_col'])

dt_m.groupby(['device_id', 'category']).apply(group_function)
```

However, I definitely agree with @piRSquared that it would be very helpful to see a full example including expected output.